# Selenium .close() triggers WebDriverException: chrome not reachable

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

This is my env:

- Ubuntu 20 LTS
- selenium 3.141.0
- google-chrome-stable 101.0.4951.64-1
- ChromeDriver 101.0.4951.41

I run this simple code in headless mode (I do not need the GUI):

```
chrome_options = Options()  
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

# get a web page
browser.get("myUrl")


# signing in...
username = browser.find_element_by_name("user")
password = browser.find_element_by_name("pass")
submit_button = browser.find_element_by_xpath("...")
username.send_keys("user")
password.send_keys("pass")
submit_button.click()
print('User logged in...')


# Click on the update button in the next page
update_button = browser.find_element_by_id('barbaz')
update_button.click()
browser.close()
```

This code worked fine with older versions of google-chrome-stable and ChromeDriver. Strangely enough, now `browser.close()` triggers this error:

> WebDriverException: Message: chrome not reachable
> (Session info: headless chrome=101.0.4951.64)

What is happening?

**Edit:**

`browser.quit()` instead of `browser.close()` seems fixing. I leave this question open, in the case anyone would like to explain the reason behind that.

Comment: I do believe the latest versions of chromedriver will throw some exceptions when closing if it's the last window open.   It used to close the driver's current tab/window and if that were the last tab/window open the driver would quit gracefully.  Now it's best not to use .close() at all unless you are closing a single tab/window and then switching the driver to an active window handle. (so only when you have multiple tabs/windows)

Answer (score 1):

`browser.quit()` and `browser.close()` are for closing all tabs and terminate session and only close running tab respectively. So if only when using close, error just shows your running tab is not available.